# Angular HTML Fullscreen Video Autoplay Not Working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, video, autoplay

Can anyone explain why this autoplay video is not working in chrome?

The video is stored in firebase storage. It plays when you visit a page and then go back to home page, but not when you first enter the page on refresh. It is an angular 6 application as well.

```
  <video autoplay muted loop>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gortonluxury.appspot.com/o/videos%2Fhero-video.mp4?alt=media&token=1231bda8-4240-4c1d-a0b9-9c5b50b320d0">
  </video>
```

Comment: Assuming your Chrome is up to date... I don't think it's a Chrome issue - copying that code into an otherwise empty HTML document and opening it in Chrome plays the video (_with some stuttering, not sure if that's a compression issue_)...  making me think it's an issue on the Angular side of things. No errors or anything else in your console? To be sure it's an Angular thing, can you try sticking that code in the root `index.html` and make sure it plays that way, and then when you put it in a component it doesn't?

Comment: Possibly an Angular issue. I'll try that, good idea. Yes fully updated Chrome, it is inside of a component with video 100vh and 100vw. No console or any errors. I can navigate to another page then back to home and it plays flawlessly. Wondering if its a loading issue when the page first originally loads.

Comment: Interesting...putting it in root index.html folder made it run no problems on first page load. Definitely an angular component issue? Cannot see why though.

Comment: Any thoughts as to why it won't autoplay in angular component?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
<video loop muted autoplay oncanplay="this.play()" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Using `onloadedmetadata` & `oncanplay="this.play()"< are the javascript solutions to getting it to load on an Angular 6 project.

Comment: Its not working when set onloadedmetadata="this.muted = false"

Answer (score 11):

For a pure Angular solution, we would need to use Angular events and a template variable:

```
<video #video 
    (canplay)="video.play()"
    (loadedmetadata)="video.muted = true"
    ...// as before
</video>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can globally override video[autoplay] tag like a 'pure angular' solution

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'video[autoplay]',
    host: {
        'autoplay': '',
        'oncanplay': 'this.play()',
        'onloadedmetadata': 'this.muted = true'
    }
})
export class VideoAutoplayDirective {}
```

Answer (score 1):

i spend hours on this problem and find the solution:

```html
    <video [autoplay]="ture" [muted]="true" [loop]="true" src="{{src}}"></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following was enough in my case, to have Angular 10 autoplay video like a GIF:

```
<video
  src="...mp4"
  type="video/mp4"
  playsinline
  loop
  autoplay
  [muted]="true"
></video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also please don't forget to check the autoplay policy for chrome:

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

Answer (score 0):

In **2024**, video won't autoplay in Win11 Edge unless:

```
<video [autoplay]="true" [muted]="true" [loop]="true" [playsInline]="true">
  <source [src]="videoPath" type="video/mp4" />
  {{ "noVideoTag" | translate }}
</video>
```

(use line with **video** tag, pasted whole fragment from my code)

Answer (score -1):

<video src="...mp4" type="video/mp4" playsinline loop autoplay [muted]="true"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

it is required video to be muted so it could autoplay

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).